# F# struct with arithmetic operators visible in C#

Tags: c#, f#, operator-overloading

I'm trying to implement a simple struct for 3-dimensional points. For performance reasons, I'd like to have that as a struct. I'd like to have it generic (at least for `System.Int32` and `System.Double`), and have arithmetic operators defined. I'm planning to use that in a mixed F#/C# solution.

Stripping down everything to 1D for simplicity of the code, here's what I started with:

```
[<Struct>]
type Point<'T> = 
    val X: 'T
    new(x) = { X = x}
    static member inline (+) (p1: Point<'U> when 'U: (static member (+): 'U * 'U -> 'U), p2: Point<'U>): Point<'U> = 
        Point<_>(p1.X + p2.X)
```

The type arguments on the `(+)` operator need to be written in terms of 'U rather than 'T, otherwise the compiler complains that the type constraints should be on the 'T argument of `Point`.

That works fine in F#, I can write

```
let p1 = Point(2.0)
let sum = p1 + p1
```

In C#:

```
var p = new Point<double>(1);
var sum = p + p;
```

That does not compile, saying `Operator + cannot by applied to operands of type Point<double> and Point<double>`

If I look at the compiled F# code in dotpeek, it says that the `+` operator on type `Point<T>` has signature `+(Point<???>,Point<???>): Point<???>`. I presume this is a result of me having to write the type constraint in terms of 'U - and probably that also triggers the C# compiler not finding the operator.

I can work around this problem by defining an F# module with operators:

```
module Ops = 
    let inline Add(p1, p2: Point<_>) = p1 + p2
```

With that, I can do addition in C# via `Ops.Add(p1,p2)` - but that's obviously not as easily readable as the `+` operator.

If I try to attach the type constraint for addition at the top level, like this:

```
[<Struct>]
type Point<'T when 'T: (static member (+): 'T * 'T -> 'T)> = 
    val X: 'T
    new(x) = { X = x}
    static member inline (+) (p1: Point<'T>, p2: Point<'T>): Point<'T> = 
        Point<_>(p1.X + p2.X)
```

then I get a compiler error at `new(x) = { X = x}`, saying `This code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable ^T when ^T: (static member...) could not be generalized because it would escape its scope`.

Is there any way of exposing the `+` operator in way that the C# compiler is happy with?

**Update**:
The fact that the operator is marked as `inline` does not have a major bearing on the result: I can define

```
[<Struct>]
type Nothing<'T> =
    val X: 'T
    new(x) = { X = x}
    static member inline (+) (p1: Nothing<'T>, p2: Nothing<'T>): Nothing<'T> = 
        Nothing<_>(p1.X)
```

and use this `+` operator just fine in C#:

```
var p1 = new Nothing<double>(1);
var sum = p1 + p1;
```

Answer (score 3):

`inline` is a feature unique to the F# compiler which C# does not support. You will have to define (at least) the operators for `int32` and `double` explicitly.

`inline` functions get inlined by the F# compiler, replacing the generic parameter(s) with *compile-time known* types. The *generic* function is *in general* not callable at runtime.
A few exceptions, where the implementation does dynamic dispatch (see e.g. [AdditionDynamic](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/8a897723b74b5dbcfacbaef86e46755fb403074b/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L2557)) *do* work at runtime but are slower than their `inline`d equivalents. Another exception is non-generic `inline` functions, where the `inline` metadata is simply ignored by the C# compiler.

`inline` is contagious, all functions calling `inline` functions must be `inline` themselves up the call tree to where all type parameters to the callee are known *at compile time*. This explains the `... would escape its scope` error. Consequently, if `inline` ends up at assembly boundaries, these functions are not consumable from non-F# projects.

**Update**: You are right, marking the operator `inline` without actually using SRTPs ([Statically Resolved Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters)) has no effect: the type `T` has no constraints, so does not need to be known at compile time:

```
let inline Add(p1: Nothing<'T>, p2: Nothing<'T>) = Nothing<_>(p1.X)
```

has signature

> ```
> val inline Add : p1:Nothing<'T> * p2:Nothing<'T> -> Nothing<'T>
> ```

as soon as you actually make use of the `inline` feature (here for being able to use `+`), `T` is known to have some constraints:

```
let inline Add(p1: Nothing<_>, p2: Nothing<_>) = p1.X + p2.X
```

has signature

> ```
> val inline Add :
>   p1:Nothing< ^a> * p2:Nothing< ^b> ->  ^c
>     when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^c)
> ```

From C# perspective:

```
// normal (runtime) generics: works
let inline Add(p1: Nothing<'T>, p2: Nothing<'T>) = Nothing<_>(p1.X)
// SRTPs decalred only: works
let inline Add(p1: Nothing<(^T)>, p2: Nothing<(^T)>) = Nothing<_>(p1.X)
// SRTPs (requires member (+)), needs type annotation, slow (using AdditionDynamic, that is reflection), may fail at runtime (if no + operator)
let inline Add(p1: Nothing<(^T)>, p2: Nothing<(^T)>) = Nothing<_>(p1.X + p2.X)
// needs type annotation, guaranteed failure at runtime (no dynamic polyfill)
let inline Add(p1: Nothing<(^T)>, p2: Nothing<(^T)>) = Nothing<_>(p1.X %% p2.X)
```

Now, if we use one of these functions as operators, only non-SRTP will work:

```
static member inline (*) (p1: Nothing<'T>, p2: Nothing<'T>) : Nothing<'T> = Nothing(p1.X) // fine
```

having the SRTP declaration is already enough:

```
static member inline (+) (p1: Nothing<(^a)>, p2: Nothing<(^a)>) : Nothing<(^a)> = Nothing(p1.X) // can not be used fom C#
```

Why is that? **C# does not support generic operators** at all (there are a few requests in [dotnet/csharplang](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang)), while in F# they can be `inline`d. And indeed, if we look at the decompiled sources:

```
// introduces new generic parameter `a`
public static Nothing<a> operator +(Nothing<a> p1, Nothing<a> p2)
// uses T from containing struct
public static Nothing<T> operator *(Nothing<T> p1, Nothing<T> p2)
```

Whether the `'T when 'T: (static member (+): 'T * 'T -> 'T)` constraint is on the struct or the operator does not make a difference: we'll always end up with a *generic* operator.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to verify that `inline` is the culprit, see my update to the question.

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer I suspect this works because no actual inline function is involved. I’ll check later today.